# When displaying an image in my directory, how to add a return (or back) button to it?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have coded in php/html a page where people can upload their files/images and on the same page it shows which files are in your current upload folder.
People can click on a specific file on that page and the file will be shown in the webbrowser. Lets say someone clicks image.jpg than that image will open. But the problem is, the image isn't embedded into a html/css script or what ever, it just shows the image.

How can I code a *back* or *return button* to that image? So that the people can return to the file-upload page?

**Here is my code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Student Notes</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src=".sorttable.js"></script>

  <style>
  .upload{
    position: absolute;
    top: 400px;
    right: 800px;
    } 
    #back{
    position: absolute;
    top:70%; 
    left:20%;
} 

.back {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #fff6af;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #fff6af;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #fff6af;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffec64), color-stop(1, #ffab23));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffec64', endColorstr='#ffab23',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#ffec64;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #ffaa22;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#6e4b06;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 24px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #ffee66;
}
.back:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffab23), color-stop(1, #ffec64));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffab23', endColorstr='#ffec64',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#ffab23;
}
.back:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;

}
  </style>


</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">

    <h1>Student Notes</h1>

    <table class="sortable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Filename</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Size <small>(bytes)</small></th>
          <th>Date Modified</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <?php
        // Opens directory
        $myDirectory=opendir("./uploads/graphics/");

        // Gets each entry
        while($entryName=readdir($myDirectory)) {
          $dirArray[]=$entryName;
        }

        // Finds extensions of files
        function findexts ($filename) {
          $filename=strtolower($filename);
          //$exts=split("[/\\.]", $filename);
          $n=count($exts)-1;
          $exts=$exts[$n];
          return $exts;
        }

        // Closes directory
        closedir($myDirectory);

        // Counts elements in array
        $indexCount=count($dirArray);

        // Sorts files
        sort($dirArray);

        // Loops through the array of files
        for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {

          // Allows ./?hidden to show hidden files
          if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']=="hidden")
          {$hide="";
          $ahref="./";
          $atext="Hide";}
          else
          {$hide=".";
          $ahref="./?hidden";
          $atext="Show";}
          if(substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != $hide) {

          // Gets File Names
          $name=$dirArray[$index];
          $namehref = "uploads/graphics/".$dirArray[$index];
          //$namehref=$dirArray[$index];

          // Gets Extensions 
          $extn=findexts($dirArray[$index]); 

          // Gets file size 
         $size=number_format(filesize("./uploads/graphics/".$dirArray[$index]))."&nbsp;";         

          // Gets Date Modified Data
          $modtime=date("M j Y g:i A", filemtime("./uploads/graphics/".$dirArray[$index]))."&nbsp;";
          $timekey=date("YmdHis", filemtime("./uploads/graphics/".$dirArray[$index]))."&nbsp;";


          // Prettifies File Types, add more to suit your needs.
          switch ($extn){
            case "png": $extn="PNG Image"; break;
            case "jpg": $extn="JPEG Image"; break;
            case "svg": $extn="SVG Image"; break;
            case "gif": $extn="GIF Image"; break;
            case "ico": $extn="Windows Icon"; break;
            case "doc": $extn="MS DOC"; break;
            case "docx": $extn="MS DOCX"; break;
            case "odt": $extn="Open Office DOC"; break;

            case "txt": $extn="Text File"; break;
            case "log": $extn="Log File"; break;
            case "htm": $extn="HTML File"; break;
            case "php": $extn="PHP Script"; break;
            case "js": $extn="Javascript"; break;
            case "css": $extn="Stylesheet"; break;
            case "pdf": $extn="PDF Document"; break;

            case "zip": $extn="ZIP Archive"; break;
            case "bak": $extn="Backup File"; break;

            default: $extn=strtoupper($extn)." File"; break;
          }

          // Separates directories
          if(is_dir($dirArray[$index])) {
            $extn="&lt;Directory&gt;"; 
            $size="&lt;Directory&gt;"; 
            $class="dir";
          } else {
            $class="file";
          }

          // Cleans up . and .. directories 
          if($name=="."){$name=". (Current Directory)"; $extn="&lt;System Dir&gt;";}
          if($name==".."){$name=".. (Parent Directory)"; $extn="&lt;System Dir&gt;";}

          // Print 'em
          print("
          <tr class='$class'>
            <td><a href='./$namehref'>$name</a></td>
            <td><a href='./$namehref'>$extn</a></td>
            <td><a href='./$namehref'>$size</a></td>
            <td sorttable_customkey='$timekey'><a href='./$namehref'>$modtime</a></td>
          </tr>");
          }
        }
      ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <h2></h2>
    <h2><a href='index.html'>Go Home</a></h2>

    <form class="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_graphics.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="512000000" />
    <a class="color">Send this file:</a><input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
    </form>    
  </div>

   <div id="back">
   <button class="back" type="button" onclick="history.back();">Back</button>
   <div>

</body>

</html>
```

**and the upload.php:**

```
<?php

$uploaddir = 'uploads/graphics/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

//echo "<p>";

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
header('Location: dir_graphics.php');
//echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
   echo "Upload failed";
}
//echo "</p>";
//echo '<pre>';
//echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
//print_r($_FILES);
//print "</pre>";

?>
```

I hope I have given you enough information!

Thank you

Mieer

***EDIT:***

```
<htmL>
<head>

<style>
iframe[seamless] { 
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 20%;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>



<div class="iframe" >

<?php

include ('dir_graphics.php');

iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.src =  ('$namehref');
iframe.style.display = "block";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);

?>
<div>

</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way would be to serve a common page with an *iFrame*. You can then have the navigation controls outside of the *iFrame*, while you control the document to show within in.

Otherwise you have to just rely on the browser's navigation buttons to get the user back to your website.

Comment: I will try this iFrame you spoke of. Thank you for you time kind stranger!

Comment: Anytime, just post here if you need any help as I will get the notification. The trick is to heavily style the iframe so you can not tell it exists (and try and make it as much of the page as possible). This is a common technique used by banks on e-ecommerce websites when they ask for your bank details. The e-commerce site never deals with your card details and just serves the banks webpage, and then waits for a success or unauthorised response from the bank.

Comment: Interesting, I will try it out and upload the practical solution here for other helpless tech-people to see :)

Comment: I have made an edit, in order for you to see and judge it, is it near the right path?

Comment: Yeah that is the sort of thing I would go for.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of linking directly to the file, you could pass the file name to a separate php script. That script could present the file in some html that has an link back to the previous page.

It would be a good idea to validate the file passed is okay to show. That is, make sure the file exists in the upload direcotry and someone is not trying to show the '../../etc/passwd' file or similar.

In general serving user-uploaded content is fraught with security concerns, but that is another matter.

Comment: Good one, i'll try to consider it :)